# ESLint no-params-reassign will not override (Prettier, VS Code, AirBNB style)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

Using ESLint/Prettier in VS Code with the AirBNB JS style guide. Trying to override rules in the style guide so that they warn instead of not compiling, and they are not overriding. I read the ESLint thing about [hierarchy](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats) and based on my file structure (package.json and .eslintrc.json in the same directory), the eslint file should override. One thing that may be the issue is that I have no .prettierrc file? Do I need one?

A few things I've tried:

- adding "root":"true" to .eslintrc.json
- moving .eslintrc.json into the exact directory my files are in (just inside of a components folder)
- moving the "extends" bit of .eslintrc.json to the end of the file versus the beginning
- using "overrides" instead of "rules"
- using "warn" and "off" and 1 and 0 in overrides

here is my .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "root": "true",
  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "prettier", "airbnb"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/self-closing-comp": "warn",
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
  }
}
```

here are my devDependencies in package.json right now:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-config-wesbos": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Have tried almost everything on the forum that seems related, and no luck. Is my config in here wrong? no-params-reassign is really what is giving me the most trouble.